# Write a program that sums a series of (postive) integers entered by the user, excluding all the numbers greater than 100

Tags: python-3.x

Hello to the Community,

I am Harrmesh, new to the world of programming and desire to create a skillset in Python programming.

I am stuck with a chapter exercise question from the book authored by Charles Dierbach.

I do not wish to copy, paste any programs but yes I want to use my own logic to create one.

I am pasting the code, Kindly assist and review the code written and if any other logic is to be tried.

Thank you.

```
total = 0
x = int(input('Enter a postive integer: '))

if x > 100:
    print('Input valid integer')
elif x <=-1:
    print('input valid integer')

y = int(input('Enter a postive integer: '))

if y > 100:
    print('Input valid integer')
elif y <=-1:
    print('input valid integer')
else:
    total = x + y
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0
x = int(input('Enter a postive integer: '))
y = int(input('Enter a postive integer: '))

if x > 100 or x < 0:
   print('Input valid integer - {}'.format(x))

if y > 100 or y < 0:
   print('Input valid integer - {}'.format(y))

print(x+y)
```